# SPI slave block without output?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, spi

I implement SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) slave. it is 3 wire block: clk, chip select and mosi. These wires are input std_logic.

Can I implement SPI slave without output?

Does it make sense an implementation without output in VHDL/FPGA?

Comment: It's the same implementation, without calling the SPI_Write()...or whatever function that sends data. "Does it make sense an implementation without output", you asked for it so you'd know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to have SPI target (slave) devices that only have an output or only have an input.

SPI DACs are often SPI data output only.

Single-channel ADCs can be an SPI data source only. Many have configuration registers to write to and multi-channel devices have channel select registers but some single-channel devices have neither.

An example SPI device with a MOSI connection but no MISO is the Texas Instruments DAC8531 Digital-To-Analogue Converter. You can find the datasheet easily enough and examine the internal structure and functions yourself.

Comment: if i have only output signals, how can I define them in VHDL code? I can't read from "out" object.

Comment: @FrankiLee, you have an SPI slave so your VHDL design (not code, that's software) has three inputs and no output, as per your question. So what output signals do you mean? It's not for the SPI bus, is it.

Comment: Spi master has only outputs, all my output signals were designed by using internal signals.

Comment: @FrankiLee, read your own question: "I implement SPI slave". Not you implement SPI master. You're being very confusing. Go back to your question before saying any more.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you only need to receive data from master, your slave does not need to have an output. Many chips operate like this.

Comment: could you suggest a reference about SPI slave without output? In a block diagram I am working on, there are a bit counter, bit selectin block (shift bits) ,3 flip flop blocks and one FIFO block. 1-Flip Flop improve the speed, 2-Flip Flop receives 8 bits and sends them to 3-Flip Flop. When 3- Flip flop is full (8 bits), 2-Flip Flop starts a new filling with bits. In the block diagram there is the FIFO block. I have thought FIFO block should be connected with CLk signal, but if it doesn’t have output, I have no idea how FIFO should be implemented.