# DMA from IP catalog(VIVADO) in my design

Tags: spi, vivado, dma

**1. Question**

I have being studying Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) protocol and Direct memory access(DMA). The VHDL-Implementation of SPI slave is done. The next my step is simulation DMA. I am going to use a block in IP cataloge of VIVADO.

It is the corresponding block:

[image]

I check `veo.file` and the folloing input/output ports are there:

```
//----------- Begin Cut here for INSTANTIATION Template ---// INST_TAG
axi_dma_2 your_instance_name (
  .s_axi_lite_aclk(s_axi_lite_aclk),                // input wire s_axi_lite_aclk
  .m_axi_s2mm_aclk(m_axi_s2mm_aclk),                // input wire m_axi_s2mm_aclk
  .axi_resetn(axi_resetn),                          // input wire axi_resetn
  .s_axi_lite_awvalid(s_axi_lite_awvalid),          // input wire s_axi_lite_awvalid
  .s_axi_lite_awready(s_axi_lite_awready),          // output wire s_axi_lite_awready
  .s_axi_lite_awaddr(s_axi_lite_awaddr),            // input wire [9 : 0] s_axi_lite_awaddr
  .s_axi_lite_wvalid(s_axi_lite_wvalid),            // input wire s_axi_lite_wvalid
  .s_axi_lite_wready(s_axi_lite_wready),            // output wire s_axi_lite_wready
  .s_axi_lite_wdata(s_axi_lite_wdata),              // input wire [31 : 0] s_axi_lite_wdata
  .s_axi_lite_bresp(s_axi_lite_bresp),              // output wire [1 : 0] s_axi_lite_bresp
  .s_axi_lite_bvalid(s_axi_lite_bvalid),            // output wire s_axi_lite_bvalid
  .s_axi_lite_bready(s_axi_lite_bready),            // input wire s_axi_lite_bready
  .s_axi_lite_arvalid(s_axi_lite_arvalid),          // input wire s_axi_lite_arvalid
  .s_axi_lite_arready(s_axi_lite_arready),          // output wire s_axi_lite_arready
  .s_axi_lite_araddr(s_axi_lite_araddr),            // input wire [9 : 0] s_axi_lite_araddr
  .s_axi_lite_rvalid(s_axi_lite_rvalid),            // output wire s_axi_lite_rvalid
  .s_axi_lite_rready(s_axi_lite_rready),            // input wire s_axi_lite_rready
  .s_axi_lite_rdata(s_axi_lite_rdata),              // output wire [31 : 0] s_axi_lite_rdata
  .s_axi_lite_rresp(s_axi_lite_rresp),              // output wire [1 : 0] s_axi_lite_rresp
  .m_axi_s2mm_awaddr(m_axi_s2mm_awaddr),            // output wire [31 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_awaddr
  .m_axi_s2mm_awlen(m_axi_s2mm_awlen),              // output wire [7 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_awlen
  .m_axi_s2mm_awsize(m_axi_s2mm_awsize),            // output wire [2 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_awsize
  .m_axi_s2mm_awburst(m_axi_s2mm_awburst),          // output wire [1 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_awburst
  .m_axi_s2mm_awprot(m_axi_s2mm_awprot),            // output wire [2 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_awprot
  .m_axi_s2mm_awcache(m_axi_s2mm_awcache),          // output wire [3 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_awcache
  .m_axi_s2mm_awvalid(m_axi_s2mm_awvalid),          // output wire m_axi_s2mm_awvalid
  .m_axi_s2mm_awready(m_axi_s2mm_awready),          // input wire m_axi_s2mm_awready
  .m_axi_s2mm_wdata(m_axi_s2mm_wdata),              // output wire [31 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_wdata
  .m_axi_s2mm_wstrb(m_axi_s2mm_wstrb),              // output wire [3 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_wstrb
  .m_axi_s2mm_wlast(m_axi_s2mm_wlast),              // output wire m_axi_s2mm_wlast
  .m_axi_s2mm_wvalid(m_axi_s2mm_wvalid),            // output wire m_axi_s2mm_wvalid
  .m_axi_s2mm_wready(m_axi_s2mm_wready),            // input wire m_axi_s2mm_wready
  .m_axi_s2mm_bresp(m_axi_s2mm_bresp),              // input wire [1 : 0] m_axi_s2mm_bresp
  .m_axi_s2mm_bvalid(m_axi_s2mm_bvalid),            // input wire m_axi_s2mm_bvalid
  .m_axi_s2mm_bready(m_axi_s2mm_bready),            // output wire m_axi_s2mm_bready
  .s2mm_prmry_reset_out_n(s2mm_prmry_reset_out_n),  // output wire s2mm_prmry_reset_out_n
  .s_axis_s2mm_tdata(s_axis_s2mm_tdata),            // input wire [7 : 0] s_axis_s2mm_tdata
  .s_axis_s2mm_tkeep(s_axis_s2mm_tkeep),            // input wire [0 : 0] s_axis_s2mm_tkeep
  .s_axis_s2mm_tvalid(s_axis_s2mm_tvalid),          // input wire s_axis_s2mm_tvalid
  .s_axis_s2mm_tready(s_axis_s2mm_tready),          // output wire s_axis_s2mm_tready
  .s_axis_s2mm_tlast(s_axis_s2mm_tlast),            // input wire s_axis_s2mm_tlast
  .s2mm_introut(s2mm_introut),                      // output wire s2mm_introut
  .axi_dma_tstvec(axi_dma_tstvec)                  // output wire [31 : 0] axi_dma_tstvec
);
// INST_TAG_END ------ End INSTANTIATION Template ---------
```

There are so many ports for slave and for master. **Did use a block correctly?**

The SPI Slave block has 3 port only. DMA block more than 20.

Do you use AXI Direct memory access block?

**2. Question**

I have read this post [SPI slave block without output?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/567870/spi-slave-block-without-output). I did the same concept, without output port. if I dont have output, how can I connect SPI slave with DAM block or others?

Answer (score 0):

Memory interfaces have many ports, and you have two memory interfaces here: one which your soft CPU uses to control the DMA controller, and one the DMA controller uses to access main memory.

The former is a "light" interface, as these are register accesses, so consecutive accesses are unlikely, and no burst transfers are required.

Typically, these would be connected to the same AXI bus, with adapters and arbiters inserted as needed (one arbiter that switches between CPU and DMA accesses to memory, one adapter to adjust the interface between the burst capable full interface and the lite interface, and one adapter to adjust the interface between the write-only "s2mm" interface and the read-write capable memory bus.

If you only implement one direction of SPI, then no data will be transferred in the other direction (probably, zeros will be output), which makes the requirement for a DMA reader unnecessary (which is why its ports don't exist).

Comment: Q2: In the post I attached, an user wrote that many blocks have no output and if I need to receive data, SPI slave will have no output. it means there is no MISO signal, right?

Comment: Q1: DMA is a " connector" between SPI slave block and memory...SPi slave will receive data and via DMA save it in memory. Do I need output in SPI slave block? Can I connect SPI and DMA without output signals of SPI?

Comment: Yes, the output is optional. The DMA has neither an output port nor a memory read interface for data because "Enable Read Channel" is deactivated.