# Connection DMA block with SPI quad block in Vivado

Tags: spi, vivado, dma

**Question 1**

I am working on a simulation DMA transfer. it should be connected with SPI slave. The SPI slave has the following ports:

```
clk:      in std_logic;
rst:      in std_logic;  
spi_clk:  in std_logic; -- spi clock
spi_cs:   in std_logic; -- spi ship select
spi_mosi: in std_logic  -- Master Out Slave In  (MOSI)
```

SPI slave has NO output ports, it receive bits and group a byte ans saved this byte in FIFO. DMA should be the next "store" of the bytes.

First, it was a big question how block has no output and I found the post "[SPI slave block without output?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/567870/spi-slave-block-without-output?noredirect=1&lq=1)" Users provided an example where it is [used](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/567889/287151) and gave some explanation.

Unfortunately I cant comment / ask in this post, so I created a new one.

**questions**:

1. If a block has no outputs, how can it be connected with another block, in my case with DMA?
2. Will Interrupt be created by SPI slave or Zynq?

Comment: The receiver FIFO has 'outputs'. It has a data output, empty/full status, and a dequeue signal to control it.

Comment: @MituRaj This FIFO is a part of SPI slave block, so it has no outputs

Comment: Huh? What kind of design is that if you can't take out the data from FIFO??? Then you should probably fix your slave first.

Comment: @MituRaj It is not my implementation. I implement DMA transfer...The author of SPI slave block is sure his implementation works and is correct.

Comment: You misinterpreted the author's implementation then. What's the use of filling a bucket, if you can't take the water out of it? Ask yourself.